# Regex: How to make domain name mandatory in validating email Id

Tags: regex, angular

I am using the following regex in my angular applicaton's validators for validating email id.

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$').
```

This works fine for some of the email patterns.

However, the email ids like test@.com is also considered a valid email id.

I wan to make the domain name mandatory in the regex so that the user always enters some string before entering '.com' (or .in , .co etc)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Your current pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hWxYA4/1) already disallows `test@.com`.  What is your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No Tim, it accepts .com right after the @. I need to make sure that there is some string before '.com'

Comment: I disagree/don't believe your observations.  Can you try entering an account manager name before testing out the email box?

Comment: Tim, I have added the updated screen shots.

Comment: There appears to be a problem with the `Validators` package you are using, and not necessarily with the regex pattern, since the pattern clearly works in @TimBiegeleisen 's example.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 3):

That thing you can do without any Regex angular provide default validator do like this :

Ts File

```
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
```

HTML File

```
 <p class="error" *ngIf="signin['email'].errors && signinForm.get('email').touched">
<span class="error-message" 
*ngIf="signin['email'].errors.required">Email is a required field</span>
<span class="error-message" *ngIf="signin['email'].errors.email">Email ID is not valid</span>
</p>
```

**And if you want to use regex then go with this.**

```
'^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$'
```

**Use like this**

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the following will do the job (I do not have Angular):

```
^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$
```

The difference is that I removed the `.` from the allowed characters after `@` - especially considering that you force a `.` anyway before TLD.

---

Note: your regex seems way too simple even for non-exotic e-mail addresses. You might want to do a search on the net to find some "proper" regex validators for e-mail addresses.

Comment: @Toto: I am bit confused. The words of your comment make me think that I said / wrote something wrong. The content at those links looks like a proof of my "note". So, which was your intention? :) Tnx.

Comment: No problem. That was my other thought.